# Array loosing values

Tags: c, arrays

It seems simple enough, query 15 records and put them in an array.
The code compiles and runs, but the array looses the values entered into it.
I print the values as they are entered into the array, and it appears correct.  Though in a for loop, the first row is correct but incorrect after that.
The code:

```
printf("SQL returned %d rows\n", mysql_num_rows(res)) ;

i = 0 ;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) 
{
    sscanf(row[0], "%lf", &data[i][0]) ;
    sscanf(row[1], "%lf", &data[i][1]) ;    // bid will always be below ask
    sscanf(row[2], "%lf", &data[i][2]) ;    // offer = ask in this DB
    sscanf(row[3], "%lf", &data[i][3]) ;    // mid = average of all bid/ask for each minute
    data[i][4] = 0 ;                        // MA5
    data[i][5] = 0 ;                        // MA15

    printf("%.0lf   %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5]) ;

    i++ ;
}

printf("\n") ;

for (j=0; j<15; j++)
    printf("%.0lf   %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", data[j][0], data[j][1], data[j][2], data[j][3], data[j][4], data[j][5]) ;
```

The first 15 rows match what is in the database, but only the first row of the for loop is printing correct values.

```
SQL returned 15 rows
1506594851  150.912000  150.932000  150.909265  0.000000    0.000000
1506594792  150.921000  150.941000  150.925761  0.000000    0.000000
1506594731  150.940000  150.963000  150.959714  0.000000    0.000000
1506594674  150.949000  150.971000  150.969609  0.000000    0.000000
1506594611  150.954000  150.976000  150.957382  0.000000    0.000000
1506594551  150.940000  150.964000  150.935012  0.000000    0.000000
1506594492  150.906000  150.927000  150.910357  0.000000    0.000000
1506594431  150.881000  150.906000  150.865748  0.000000    0.000000
1506594371  150.822000  150.846000  150.821062  0.000000    0.000000
1506594851  150.912000  150.932000  150.909265  0.000000    0.000000
1506594251  150.768000  150.794000  150.751332  0.000000    0.000000
1506594194  150.701000  150.724000  150.715379  0.000000    0.000000
1506594134  150.740000  150.757000  150.754935  0.000000    0.000000
1506594076  150.749000  150.772000  150.758302  0.000000    0.000000
1506594011  150.755000  150.774000  150.753550  0.000000    0.000000

1506594851  150.912000  150.932000  150.909265  0.000000    0.000000
1506594251  150.768000  150.794000  150.751332  0.000000    0.000000
1506594194  150.701000  150.724000  150.715379  0.000000    0.000000
1506594134  150.740000  150.757000  150.754935  0.000000    0.000000
1506594076  150.749000  150.772000  150.758302  0.000000    0.000000
1506594011  150.755000  150.774000  150.753550  0.000000    0.000000
1506594492  150.906000  150.927000  150.910357  0.000000    0.000000
1506594431  150.881000  150.906000  150.865748  0.000000    0.000000
1506594371  150.822000  150.846000  150.821062  0.000000    0.000000
1506594312  150.798000  150.824000  150.798255  0.000000    0.000000
0   0.000000    97795656476117789550858635641226156856160388037177544822378925818587375507523129063032745851654482135492440234643161088.000000  270721760232452916408621777331997134952922302290494666767651053623661202019325513025428600003963936853860599692342289934319616.000000   0.000000    0.000000
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

I am unable to figure out why the array is changing, though the print statements are identical, only one in a *while* and the other in a *for* loop.
Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h"
#include <string.h> // strncpy


int main(void)
{

int i = 0 ;
int j = 0 ;
int n = 0 ;
int position = 0 ;
double pairsid = 8 ;
char sql[300] ;

double tmpdbl = 0 ;

double data[6][15] ;    // Stamp, bid, ask, mid, SMA5, SMA15

char *server = "localhost" ;
char *user = "x" ;
char *password = "x" ; // set me first
char *database = "x";

MYSQL *con1 ;
MYSQL_RES *res ;
MYSQL_ROW row ;
con1 = mysql_init(NULL) ;

// Connect to database
if (!mysql_real_connect(con1, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "DB Connect Error %s\n", mysql_error(con1)) ;
    exit(1);
}


sprintf(sql, "(SELECT stamp, bid, ask, mid FROM oanda WHERE pairsid = %.0lf ORDER BY stamp LIMIT %d) ORDER BY stamp DESC", pairsid, 15) ;

printf("%s\n", sql) ;

if (mysql_query(con1, sql)) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error running query %s\n", mysql_error(con1)) ;
    exit(1) ; 
}

res = mysql_store_result(con1) ;    


printf("SQL returned %d rows\n", mysql_num_rows(res)) ;

i = 0 ;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) 
{
    sscanf(row[0], "%lf", &data[i][0]) ;
    sscanf(row[1], "%lf", &data[i][1]) ;    // bid will always be below ask
    sscanf(row[2], "%lf", &data[i][2]) ;    // offer = ask in this DB
    sscanf(row[3], "%lf", &data[i][3]) ;    // mid = average of all bid/ask for each minute
    data[i][4] = 0 ;                        // MA5
    data[i][5] = 0 ;                        // MA15

    printf("%.0lf   %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4], data[i][5]) ;

    i++ ;
}

printf("\n") ;

for (j=0; j<15; j++)
    printf("%.0lf   %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", data[j][0], data[j][1], data[j][2], data[j][3], data[j][4], data[j][5]) ;

printf("\n") ;

mysql_free_result(res) ;

mysql_close(con1) ;
}
```

OK, got it working now.  Thanks all

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) 
{
    sscanf(row[0], "%lf", &data[0][i]) ;
    sscanf(row[1], "%lf", &data[1][i]) ;    // bid will always be below ask
    sscanf(row[2], "%lf", &data[2][i]) ;    // offer = ask in this DB
    sscanf(row[3], "%lf", &data[3][i]) ;    // mid = average of all bid/ask for each minute
    data[4][i] = 0 ;                        // MA5
    data[5][i] = 0 ;                        // MA15

    printf("Row %d %.0lf    %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", i, data[0][i], data[1][i], data[2][i], data[3][i], data[4][i], data[5][i]) ;

    i++ ;
}

printf("\n") ;

for (j=0; j<15; j++)
    printf("%.0lf   %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", data[0][j], data[1][j], data[2][j], data[3][j], data[4][j], data[5][j]) ;
```

gives me

```
SQL returned 15 rows
Row 0 1506594851    150.912000  150.932000  150.909265  0.000000    0.000000
Row 1 1506594792    150.921000  150.941000  150.925761  0.000000    0.000000
Row 2 1506594731    150.940000  150.963000  150.959714  0.000000    0.000000
Row 3 1506594674    150.949000  150.971000  150.969609  0.000000    0.000000
Row 4 1506594611    150.954000  150.976000  150.957382  0.000000    0.000000
Row 5 1506594551    150.940000  150.964000  150.935012  0.000000    0.000000
Row 6 1506594492    150.906000  150.927000  150.910357  0.000000    0.000000
Row 7 1506594431    150.881000  150.906000  150.865748  0.000000    0.000000
Row 8 1506594371    150.822000  150.846000  150.821062  0.000000    0.000000
Row 9 1506594312    150.798000  150.824000  150.798255  0.000000    0.000000
Row 10 1506594251   150.768000  150.794000  150.751332  0.000000    0.000000
Row 11 1506594194   150.701000  150.724000  150.715379  0.000000    0.000000
Row 12 1506594134   150.740000  150.757000  150.754935  0.000000    0.000000
Row 13 1506594076   150.749000  150.772000  150.758302  0.000000    0.000000
Row 14 1506594011   150.755000  150.774000  150.753550  0.000000    0.000000

1506594851  150.912000  150.932000  150.909265  0.000000    0.000000
1506594792  150.921000  150.941000  150.925761  0.000000    0.000000
1506594731  150.940000  150.963000  150.959714  0.000000    0.000000
1506594674  150.949000  150.971000  150.969609  0.000000    0.000000
1506594611  150.954000  150.976000  150.957382  0.000000    0.000000
1506594551  150.940000  150.964000  150.935012  0.000000    0.000000
1506594492  150.906000  150.927000  150.910357  0.000000    0.000000
1506594431  150.881000  150.906000  150.865748  0.000000    0.000000
1506594371  150.822000  150.846000  150.821062  0.000000    0.000000
1506594312  150.798000  150.824000  150.798255  0.000000    0.000000
1506594251  150.768000  150.794000  150.751332  0.000000    0.000000
1506594194  150.701000  150.724000  150.715379  0.000000    0.000000
1506594134  150.740000  150.757000  150.754935  0.000000    0.000000
1506594076  150.749000  150.772000  150.758302  0.000000    0.000000
1506594011  150.755000  150.774000  150.753550  0.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that the array declaration is not exactly [15][x] where x >= 4.

Comment: How is `data` declared?

Comment: please post a [mcve]  You are not showing the array declaration

Comment: I feel dumb after reading n.m. post.  No, it's not exactly a [15][x] array, it's a [6][15] array.  I changed the array indicies to 
 sscanf(row[0], "%lf", &data[0][i]) ; 
and 
 printf("%.0lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", data[0][j], data[1][j], data[2][j], data[3][j], data[4][j], data[5][j]) ;
but still not working

Comment: Seems like it should work if you flipped all of the indices like you said.  You may want to assure that you don't populate more than 15 rows, e.g. right after i++, put: if (i>=15) break;  You'll need to update more completely in order to resolve.

Comment: regarding: `double data[6][15] ; `   That is laid out as columns, rows  The resulting data will be corrupted.  Suggest: `double data[15][6]` ;